# SSRS Report Viewer + ASP.NET Credentials 401 Exception

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, http-status-code-401

I have a report saved on a SQL2005 reporting server, and I want to return a rendered PDF of this report. I've figured this out when working with a local *.rdlc file ([and I've blogged about it](http://www.jarrettmeyer.com/2009/09/reports-in-aspnet-mvc.html)), but not when the *.rdl resides on a reporting server. I am getting a **401 Not Authorized** error at the line...

```
reportViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(reportDefinition.ReportParameters);
```

Here's the method used to render the report.

```
public byte[] Render(IReportDefinition reportDefinition)
{
    var reportViewer = new ReportViewer();
    byte[] renderedReport;
    try
    {
        var credentials = new WindowsImpersonationCredentials();
        reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://myssrsbox", UrlKind.Absolute);
        reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = credentials;
        reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = reportDefinition.Path;
        // Exception is thrown on the following line...
        reportViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(reportDefinition.ReportParameters);

        string mimeType;
        string encoding;
        string filenameExtension;
        string[] streams;
        Warning[] warnings;

        renderedReport = reportViewer.ServerReport.Render(reportDefinition.OutputType, reportDefinition.DeviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension, out streams, out warnings);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // log the error...
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        reportViewer.Dispose();
    }
    return renderedReport;
}
```

The other thing that you're missing is the WindowsImpersonationCredentials class.

```
public class WindowsImpersonationCredentials : IReportServerCredentials
{
    public bool GetFormsCredentials(out Cookie authCookie, out string userName, out string password, out string authority)
    {
        authCookie = null;
        userName = password = authority = null;
        return false;
    }

    public WindowsIdentity ImpersonationUser
    {
        get { return WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent(); }
    }

    public ICredentials NetworkCredentials
    {
        get { return null; }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("WindowsIdentity: {0} ({1})", this.ImpersonationUser.Name, this.ImpersonationUser.User.Value);
    }
}
```

Other things you may need to know...

- This is running on an intranet, and impersonation is turned on.
- Logging indicates that the impersonation user is being set correctly.
- This **does work** when running in Visual Studio (`http://localhost:devport`), and it **does work** when running on my development box (`http://localhost/myApplication`). It **does not work** when running on our test or production servers.
- I have tried solutions both with and without system.net.defaultProxy settings in web.config. Neither worked.

What am I doing wrong? Is it a server setting? Is it code? Is it web.config?

Comment: Does the impersonation user have access to the report server -- that report in particular?

Comment: Have you tried running IIS under the impersonation user on your dev machine (localhost) to closer emulate what is happening on your test server?  It sounds like a flat out permissions issue with your impersonation user against the reporting server or reporting server database.  I assume the impersonation user is a domain account.

Comment: @NYSystemsAnalyst - Yes, the impersonation user has access to the appropriate directory on the report server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We did finally figure out the problem. Our network administrators have disabled double-hopping, so while the impersonation was correctly connecting as `domain\jmeyer`, the application was still attempting to connect to the SRS box with `domain\web01$`. Why is it set up like this? Because double-hopping is a massive security hole. (Or so I was told. Does this sound like something you would read on [The Daily WTF](http://thedailywtf.com/)?)

Our solution was to create a generic `domain\ssrs_report_services` user, and connect with that user with the following network credentials

```
public class CustomCredentials : IReportServerCredentials
{
    public bool GetFormsCredentials(out Cookie authCookie, out string userName, out string password, out string authority)
    {
        authCookie = null;
        userName = password = authority = null;
        return false;
    }

    public WindowsIdentity ImpersonationUser
    {
        get { return null; }
    }

    public ICredentials NetworkCredentials
    {
        get { return new NetworkCredential("ssrs_report_services", "password", "domain") ; }
    }    
}
```

The above is the classic example solution that you can find all over the internets.

Comment: In fact, I don't think double hopping is "allowed" under any configuration.  It's not clear to me why your dev environment was working, but it was probably configured differently.

Comment: As it was explained to me, it works on dev because it doesn't count as a hop to go from localhost (as client) -> localhost (as IIS) -> SRS

Comment: FYI, the admins can configure delegation on a per server basis.  Check out: http://serverfault.com/questions/16364/is-there-a-way-to-get-kerberos-credentials-to-delegate-twice-why-not

Comment: By creating a new domain user, doesn't that mean that you won't be able to restrict the reports down to a user level though as everyone using you app will be authenticated using the same credentials? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

"Double hopping" is allowed - swith on Kerberos authentication ... (so long as it is working properly!)

Comment: Unfortunately, we developers are constrained quite a bit by the environment and have no say in the infrastructure. Thanks for giving me something new to read about, though.