# IIS 7.5 Windows Authentication failed with 401

Tags: windows, iis, windows-authentication, iis-7.5

Since we moved from IIS 7.0 to IIS 7.5 the Windows Authentication doesn't work anymore from remote requests. If I open the website on the webserver everything works fine.

**web.config:**

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<identity impersonate="true" />
<authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
        <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
```

**IIS Settings:**

```
Authentication (enabled): ASP.NET Impersonation, Windows Authentication (all others are disabled)
ApplicationPool: Managed Pipeline Mode -> Classic, Identity -> ApplicationPoolIdentity
```

**Failed Request Trace:**

```
MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS
ModuleName: WindowsAuthenticationModule
Notification: 2
HttpStatus: 401
HttpReason: Unauthorized 
HttpSubStatus: 1
ErrorCode: 2148074254 
ConfigExceptionInfo:  
Notification: AUTHENTICATE_REQUEST
ErrorCode No credentials are available in the security package (0x8009030e)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We had a two-hop problem I think. If I move our SQL/Oracle DB to the server which is running IIS it works.

So here is an article to which describes a solution.

[How to configure SQL and IIS for two hop kerberos authentication 2](http://www.phishthis.com/2009/10/24/how-to-configure-ad-sql-and-iis-for-two-hop-kerberos-authentication-2/)

or 
[SSRS Reportviewer ASP.NET Credentials 401 Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439245/ssrs-report-viewer-asp-net-credentials-401-exception)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Which client are you using? you might be running a client that is trying to pre-authenticate, but in IIS 7 we use Kernel Mode authentication by default which requires a challenge. If that is the case you can disable Kernel Mode auth by selecting the Windows Authentication entry and clicking Advanced Settings, you should see a checkbox that allows you to Disable that for the specific application and it should work if this is the problem.

Comment: After I disable it I will get two FailedTrace Request:
1st:
Request Summary
Url http://computername:80/ 
App Pool AppPoolName 
Authentication NOT_AVAILABLE
User from token  
Activity ID {00000000-0000-0000-0A00-0080000000FC} 
MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS 401.2

2nd:
Request Summary:
Url http://computername:80/ 
App Pool AppPoolName 
Authentication NTLM 
User from token domain\username 
Activity ID {00000000-0000-0000-0C00-0080000000FC} 
MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS 401.5

It looks like the first request is an PreAuthentication but I have disabled the KernelMode.

Comment: We tried it with the following clients with no success, Windows XP (Safari, Firefox, IE) and Windows 7 (Chrome, IE)